How to Configure Grafana Loki to Dynamically Collect and Filter Logs from AWS Auto-Scaling EC2 Instances?
Question:
I'm currently working on a project where I need to dynamically collect logs from AWS EC2 instances and visualize them in Grafana using Loki. Here are the specifics of my setup and requirements:

AWS Setup:

EC2 instances are part of an AWS auto-scaling group.

Instances have the same name and dynamic public IP addresses.

Logs are stored at a specific path on each instance.



Requirements:

Collect logs from all instances in the auto-scaling group.

Be able to filter and view logs from each specific instance in Grafana.

Identify server information (e.g., instance ID or hostname) in the logs so I can filter by instance.




Challenges:

Due to the dynamic nature of the auto-scaling group, instances come and go, and their IPs change.

I need a solution that automatically adapts to these changes without manual reconfiguration.


What I've Tried So Far:

I have set up a Loki instance and configured it to collect logs from a static set of instances.

I am using promtail to push logs from EC2 instances to Loki.

However, I am struggling with dynamically updating the promtail configurations as instances scale in and out.


Questions:

How can I configure promtail to dynamically discover and collect logs from all instances in my auto-scaling group?

What is the best way to include server-specific information (such as instance ID or hostname) in the logs so that I can filter by server in Grafana?

Are there any best practices or tools specifically designed to handle log collection from auto-scaling groups in AWS?


Additional Details:

I'm using AWS CloudWatch to monitor the instances, but I need more detailed log analysis in Grafana.

The logs are stored in a specific directory, e.g., /var/log/myapp/.


Any guidance or examples of configurations would be highly appreciated!
